ImportError when importing boto3 in EMR Serverless 7.2.0
I'm deploying an EMR Serverless application and using venv-pack to create the python environment for that application. The venv-pack zip is created inside a Docker container:
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 amazonlinux:2 AS base

RUN yum install -y gcc openssl-devel bzip2-devel libffi-devel tar gzip wget make
RUN wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.9.9/Python-3.9.9.tgz && \
    tar xzf Python-3.9.9.tgz && cd Python-3.9.9 && \
    ./configure --enable-optimizations && \
    make altinstall

ENV VIRTUAL_ENV=/opt/venv
RUN python3.9 -m venv $VIRTUAL_ENV --copies
RUN cp -r /usr/local/lib/python3.9/* $VIRTUAL_ENV/lib/python3.9/
ENV PATH=$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH

RUN python3.9 -m pip install --upgrade pip && \
    python3.9 -m pip install venv-pack==0.2.0 
COPY requirements.txt .

RUN python3.9 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN mkdir /output && venv-pack -f -o /output/venv.tar.gz --python-prefix /home/hadoop/environment

FROM scratch AS export
COPY --from=base /output/venv.tar.gz /

When I start a new job run, I get the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):  
    File "/tmp/spark-9c672dff-e6d2-47e1-a3dc-1c25eb73691f/main.py", line 10, in <module>    
    from custom_package.custom_script import A, B, C    
    File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module 
    File "/tmp/spark-9c672dff-e6d2-47e1-a3dc-1c25eb73691f/custom_package.zip/custom_package/A.py", line 5, in <module>  
    File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module 
    File "/tmp/spark-9c672dff-e6d2-47e1-a3dc-1c25eb73691f/custom_package.zip/custom_package/D.py", line 9, in <module>  
    File "/home/hadoop/environment/lib/python3.9/site-packages/boto3/__init__.py", line 17, in <module> 
    from boto3.session import Session   
    File "/home/hadoop/environment/lib/python3.9/site-packages/boto3/session.py", line 17, in <module>  
    import botocore.session 
    File "/home/hadoop/environment/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/session.py", line 26, in <module>   
    import botocore.client  
    File "/home/hadoop/environment/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 15, in <module>    
    from botocore import waiter, xform_name 
    File "/home/hadoop/environment/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/waiter.py", line 18, in <module>    
    from botocore.docs.docstring import WaiterDocstring 
    File "/home/hadoop/environment/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/docs/__init__.py", line 15, in <module> 
    from botocore.docs.service import ServiceDocumenter 
    File "/home/hadoop/environment/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/docs/service.py", line 14, in <module>  
    from botocore.docs.client import ClientDocumenter, ClientExceptionsDocumenter   
    File "/home/hadoop/environment/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/docs/client.py", line 17, in <module>   
    from botocore.docs.example import ResponseExampleDocumenter 
    File "/home/hadoop/environment/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/docs/example.py", line 13, in <module>  
    from botocore.docs.shape import ShapeDocumenter 
    File "/home/hadoop/environment/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/docs/shape.py", line 19, in <module>    
    from botocore.utils import is_json_value_header 
    File "/home/hadoop/environment/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/utils.py", line 37, in <module> 
    import botocore.httpsession 
    File "/home/hadoop/environment/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/httpsession.py", line 22, in <module>   
    from urllib3.util.ssl_ import ( 
ImportError: cannot import name 'ssl' from 'urllib3.util.ssl_' (/home/hadoop/environment/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py)  


I tried installing boto3==1.28.58 or 1.34.155, but neither seems to work. This exact configuration also works fine on EMR 6.13.0. How do I fix the import issue?
